# Validate C# object to XSD and generate xml output

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an object which has public properties.

Say for e.g. an object called Regions and it looks something like this

> ```
> public class Region
> {
> // public properties
>  string name;
>
>  string description;
>
>  string timezone;
>
>  string regionURL;
>
>  string regioncode;
>
> }
> ```

Now I want to validate this object to region XSD which basically doesn't have all the properties which are present in the region object. And for the properties which are in the XSD I want to generate the output as XML.

The region XSD looks like

```
<xs:schema>
<xs:complexType name="region">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="URl" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="code" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Is there something inbuilt in .net which can be helpful?

Comment: When you post code, or XML etc, use the code block option on the editor. This make the code pretty and XML visible in the final posting

Comment: i don't think i quite understand the question: are you asking whether there is a way to do the validation of XML data which would be read in and checked against the schema? or whether there would be something that would automatically populate a class or collection of classes based on data that is read in?  or something else?  thanks! :)

Comment: Erm...What will you do if the validation of your object fails? Rewrite the object? Why not just use XSD.EXE to automatically generate the object for you from the XSD?

Comment: Is simply adding appropriate attributes to your class to make it fit the schema an option here?

Comment: I guess I didn't write it quite correctly. So say I have an object X with n properties in it and I have an XSD which has properties but not the same as the ones in object X. So what I need here is to generate an XML file with the data from the object X but the schema for the XML is defined in the XSD. I hope this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into implementing IXMLSerializable on your class, and generate the XML serialization via XSD that way.

There's an article about it on codeproject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/ImplementIXmlSerializable.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

1. Generate code from your region schema so you have a RegionFromXsd type. Map the data from an instance of your Regions type to your new RegionFromXsd type. Then serialise your RegionFromXsd type into XML document.
2. Populate an instance of your Regions type, serialise it to XML, then apply an XSLT which transforms the XML to a form which complies with your region XSD schema.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like the 2nd option here..but I am not able to understand that after I serialize the data to xml first..how can I apply the XSL which transforms the XML into required format based of an XSD. After I have the first XML ready all I am trying to do is filter few nodes from it based on an XSD .

Comment: You need to create the XSL transform yourself. Like I said, there is no one-step soluition you can implement to move from your Region type to a xml document other than the one you would serialise "naturally" into.